# Dell Studio 15 battery performance?

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-studio

How many hours of usage can I expect from the 6 and 9 cell batteries Dell offers with the Studio 15 (for general usage, like wifi browsing and some applications like word)?

Also, if you own a slightly older Studio 15, by how much has the battery capacity decreased over time?

I'm mostly buying the 9 cell, so if you own the Studio 15 with a 9er, please do tell me about it! But 6 cell'ers too answer, because i can then approximate the 9 cell's performance.

Comment: About half of what they print in their ads is my experience with Dell laptops :-(

Answer (score 1):

A new 6-cell? Around 2-3 hours.

A new 9-cell? Around 3-5 hours.

It depends on your use, your power settings, screen brightness, the hardware you have installed, and what external devices you have attached.

Yes, battery capacity decreases with age and use, and is dependent upon those two factors.  It varies as to how much of a decrease you will see.